# Word for a place or resource where everything can be found

Tags: single-word-requests

To give a full understanding of my question, I'll give some short background info.

I'm working on an [Easter Island website](https://easterislandtraveling.com/) where I offer travel tips of all sorts, a travel guide, tours and hotels. I'm working on the description of the site that appears when you search in Google (maximum 115 characters).

I'm looking for a word that describes a place or resource where you can find everything. This is what I have now:

> Welcome to your ultimate **metropolis** for Easter Island tourism!
>   Plan your trip and book the best hotels and tours with us.

It seems I can't use metropolis in English, right? I'm from Sweden, and in Swedish you can, but it seems you can't use this word in English like this, right? Any ideas of another word? Or any ideas of re-phrasing the description? Thank you!

Comment: You could use ***clearinghouse***.

Comment: Don't you mean "the Internet"?

Comment: *El dorado*? Not exactly, though.

Comment: Possibly "goldmine".

Comment: *heaven*......?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in that *metropolis* may not be the ideal choice here. Below are a few ideas, not all of which is a single word:

"Welcome to your (ultimate)..."

- ***hub***
- ***one-stop shop***
- ***all-in-one destination***
- ***mecca***

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Migs! I like the word "mecca", though it might be a bit political. Though, it is a powerful word that everyone understand, so that's good! Would you have any more cards up that same sleeve? Thank you!

Comment: "Resource" might work.  (I'd stay away from "mecca" if I were you.)

Comment: I like _one-stop shop_.

Comment: I accepted this as an answer in the end as it was closest to what I was looking for. In the end though, I went another direction and used "the ultimate resource" instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***Ali Baba's Cave***

> One day, Ali Baba is at work collecting and cutting firewood in the
>   forest, and he happens to overhear a group of forty thieves visiting
>   their treasure store. The treasure is in a cave, the mouth of which is
>   sealed by magic. It opens on the words "open sesame" and seals itself
>   on the words "close sesame". When the thieves are gone, Ali Baba
>   enters the cave himself, and discreetly takes a single bag of gold
>   coins home.
>
> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali_Baba#Story)

***The Cornucopia***

> The cornucopia (from Latin cornu copiae) or horn of plenty is a symbol
>   of abundance and nourishment, commonly a large horn-shaped container
>   overflowing with produce, flowers or nuts.
>
> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornucopia)

Answer (score 0):

**wonderland**

> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wonderland):
>
> a place that is filled with things that are beautiful, impressive, or surprising

Comment: that hardly suggests completeness, or even a large quantity.